# unable to create .jar file, "mvn clean install " does not work properly

Tags: java, maven

`$ java -version`

> openjdk version "9-internal"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)

`$ mvn -version`

> Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
>   Apache Maven 3.3.9
>   Maven home: /usr/share/maven
>   Java version: 9-internal, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>   Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64
>   Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
>   OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-54-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
>
> error:-
>   Failed to execute goal on project api: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.capitalone.dashboard:api:jar:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.capitalone.dashboard:core:jar:3.1.2-SNAPSHOT

Comment: for linux `gksudo gedit /etc/environment                                        
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/open-jdk"    ` //what ever is your path      $ export JAVA_HOME

Comment: Please don't just dump your error code into the search box. Give us some context. Explain in your own words what you are trying to accomplish. Expect a proportional amount of effort in an answer as you have put into the question. In this case, none.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable? :)

Comment: Ok, sorry, looks that you're using a dependency which is not present in central maven repo, see here — https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.capitalone.dashboard/core. Last version is `3.1.1`. Try to change it to `3.1.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a few reasons why Maven can't find a particular dependency.

1. It's a local dependency which needs to be built and installed in the local Maven repository first. This could be a shared module that must be copied/cloned and built on the same machine before this project can be built. Maven will place the artifact in a local repository.
2. The name or version number are incorrect in the pom file. If the artifact is available on Maven Central it could be that the specific version you are looking for is not there. Check the name and version number and search Maven Central for the artifact.
3. The Maven settings file is not setup correctly. There are 2 places where this file could be, most likely it is in the current user folder, in the .m2 folder. On Windows this would be c:\Users\current-user\.m2\settings.xml. This file has settings to tell maven where to look for dependencies. These settings depend very much on your company infrastructure. There could be a local mirror repository which holds all the dependencies you require, or there could be an internet proxy that must be configured in the .settings file.